# Typescript: How to convert an object type to paths mapper?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want to generate a paths mapper type from an object type, just like below.

```js
type NestedObject = {
  prop1: {
    prop1_1: string;
  };
  prop2: string;
  prop3: {prop3_1: string;}[];
}

// convert to
type PathsMapFromNestedObject = {
  prop1: ["prop1"];
  prop1_1: ["prop1", "prop1_1"];
  prop2: ["prop2"];
  prop3: ["prop3"];
  prop3_1: ["prop3", number, "prop3_1"]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
type Paths_<T, P extends (string | number)[] = []> = {
  [K in keyof T]: [...P, K] | (T[K] extends any[] 
    ? Paths_<T[K][number],  [...P, K & string, number]>
    : T[K] extends object 
      ? Paths_<T[K], [...P, K & string]>
      : never
  )
}[keyof T]

type Paths<T> = { 
  [
    K in Paths_<T> extends infer U 
      ? U 
      : never 
    as K extends [...any, infer L extends string] 
      ? L 
      : never
  ]: K 
}
```

`Paths_` is a recursive type which traverses through the object. It builds a union with a tuple of `string | number` for each property inside the object. The generic type `P` is used to store the current path as a tuple.

`Paths` calls the recursive type and builds an object from the union using a mapped type.

---

And here is the result.

```
type PathsMapFromNestedObject = Paths<NestedObject>
// type PathsMapFromNestedObject = {
//     prop1: ["prop1"];
//     prop1_1: ["prop1", "prop1_1"];
//     prop2: ["prop2"];
//     prop3: ["prop3"];
//     prop3_1: ["prop3", number, "prop3_1"];
// }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAchDOwIBMDyAjAVhAxsKAvFAN4BQUUYATgPZgCMAXCeRZbQwPpNSJUCWAOwDmAblYBfcRWp0ATMz5CxrWWADMzYmvXdFwASNESA2gF1xE0qVCQoABQCGwABbxOAHgAqAGgdQIAA8kQWR4KAAKJREoAB8oQQBXAFt0CCoASnNCKHMAPhyyChMAaSghKABrCBAaADMoLzNmEwA6dvs-ErM4yK9SnqCQsKhHQRBs1goAfgdnN09%207pMk1PSzP1z21s6oMoAyXgNlP1W0qjM8qahmJcHgiFDwmixcfGuZudd3bwG-No6XSgh2iwkuHxuCQgADd0qwMqRTNVag0mtZbNAnN9vAUiMQoKwTNcyhUsQscQEHk9yoI6ukoABVAlsNizJkQ5iCGH066OcJlIaPEYA1pjEB%20IR0qhQAAylOG4VBPQhszlHKhsKorGaewJVnR4Ex83gAFlHGAAGK0ZJwRAoDDYPA5MnwDy2pBoV54K4Aeh9UAxXzcZst1vd9q9%20DxpD9LPYdB4JgARGp6EmLDH-SzU3pcimOGm-PmE9x0%20JY9mOAo82o5GXM3GdC1ixp6xW2Dpc8mdEnTilzkXO2mM7GJEA)

Comment: I want to define a utility type base `Paths` that returns paths by prop name. `type PropPaths<T, K extends keyof Paths<T>> = Paths<T>[K];`. It works. And is there a better way to do it?